# Input XML output XML with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem, I can't figure out the XSL code for "transforming" an xml into another xml

**This is the input xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<output>
  <cars>
    <car>
      <id>1</id>
      <brand>Audi</brand>
      <type>A3</type>
      <license>B-01-TST</license>
    </car>
    <car>
      <id>2</id>
      <brand>Volkwagen</brand>
      <type>Golf</type>
      <license>IF-02-TST</license>
    </car>
  </cars>
  <distances>
    <distance>
      <id_car>1</id_car>
      <date>20110901</date>
      <distance>111</distance>
    </distance>
    <distance>
      <id_car>1</id_car>
      <date>20110902</date>
      <distance>23</distance>
    </distance>
    <distance>
      <id_car>1</id_car>
      <date>20110903</date>
      <distance>0</distance>
    </distance>
    <distance>
      <id_car>2</id_car>
      <date>20110901</date>
      <distance>92</distance>
    </distance>
    <distance>
      <id_car>2</id_car>
      <date>20110902</date>
      <distance>87</distance>
    </distance>
    <distance>
      <id_car>2</id_car>
      <date>20110903</date>
      <distance>132</distance>
    </distance>
  </distances>
</output>
```

**This is the output xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<cars>
  <car>
    <id>1</id> 
    <brand>Audi</brand>
    <type>A3</type>
    <license>B-01-TST</license>
    <distances>
      <distance day="20110901">111</distance>
      <distance day="20110902">23</distance>
      <distance day="20110903">0</distance>
    </distances>
  </car>
  <car>
    <id>2</id>
    <brand>Volkwagen</brand>
    <type>Golf</type>
    <license>IF-02-TST</license>
    <distances>
      <distance day="20110901">92</distance>
      <distance day="20110902">87</distance>
      <distance day="20110903">132</distance>
    </distances>
  </car>
</cars>
```

and the end for the element cars at the end I forgot.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any question asked. ???

Comment: How would the XSL code look like that makes this grouping ? do i have to use a variable that matches the id in the cars -element and distances -element ? what structure should i use to do this ? Can you give me an example? ...how would u write this code in xsl ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually quite easy to do using XSLT; the hardest part is the use of keys. Here's the code you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="distances" match="distance" use="id_car" />

  <xsl:template match="output">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="cars" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="car">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
      <distances>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('distances', id)" />
      </distances>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="distance">
    <distance day="{date}">
      <xsl:value-of select="distance" />
    </distance>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The key essentially allows you to use the `key` function to get a list of all `distance` elements with an `id_car` of a given value.

The first template handles the root and outputs only the `cars` element.

The second template handles any `car` elements, outputting them exactly as they are, but adding in a `distances` element, and with the use of the `key` function, processes any `distance` elements with the correct ID.

The last template is the 'identity' template that copies any elements that we haven't already accounted for exactly as they are; this handles the `brand`, `type`, `license` elements, and so on.